# R - Specify the directory using the package googlesheets

Tags: r, google-sheets

I use the `googlesheets` package. The default directory for spreadsheets is the root of Google Drive. I guess that I can specify the directory - like for a "normal" directory path - but I don't know how to do that.

```
gs_new(title = "MyData") # export to the root
gs_new(title = "Something/MyData") # export to the specified directory
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. You can specify paths in exactly the way you showed.

Comment: If I run a code like `gs_new(title = "Something/MyData")`, a spreadsheet named Something/MyData is created in the root directory. Or I want to create a spreadsheet named MyData in the Something directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in this question. I will try the following to see if it works. If not, I may try to use the 'googledrive' package on top of, or in replacement of, the 'googlesheets' package to do sheet creation in a list folder hierarchy. This way I can loop through a list of subfolders while creating any files inside them until all subfolders have their new files created.

So here's my thinking... When I have time to test this out, I'll let you know!

```
for(path in file_paths){
    setwd(path)
    for(file in files){
        gs_new(file)
    }
}
```

Of course, get your parent folder as a string and use list.files("string", full.names=TRUE). Then, if you have any subfolders (assuming they're created already), it'll return a list in which to loop through. If you just want to create one workbook at one location, simply setting the working directory might work. Again, I'll need to test this in multiple methods.